# How to confirm success of push request in Firebase Web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref("Test_Applicants/");

        databaseRef.push({
            firstname: first_name,
            middlename: middle_name,
            lastname: last_name,
            university: university_full_name,
            email: email_address,
            phone: phone_number,
            date: getDate(),
            docs: docURL
        }, function(error){
            //Callback failed
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Is this the right approach? How do I receive a variable or an argument from Firebase through a callback or through any other way to confirm that the data was written successfully? I'd like to upload a file if request is successful or return an error message to the user if the write fails.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref("Test_Applicants/");
        databaseRef.push({
            firstname: first_name,
            middlename: middle_name,
            lastname: last_name,
            university: university_full_name,
            email: email_address,
            phone: phone_number,
            date: getDate(),
            docs: docURL
        }, function(error){
            if (error) {
             console.error(error)
             return
            }
            console.log('Push successful')
            //add upload function here
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen child events in this case using following

```
databaseRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseRef.push().set({name:"john doe",telephone:"25400000000"}).catch((error)=>console.log(error))
```